Asymptotic consistency of the Clopper-Pearson interval
I have a series of random variables $X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$ and I want to claim that for every confidence level $c \in (0,1)$ $ClopperPearsonLower(X_n, n, c)$ converges in probability to $p$, that is for every $\epsilon>0$: $Pr[|ClopperPearsonLower(X_n, n,c) - p| > \epsilon]\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$.
Is it true? If so, I would be glad for a reference for a book that shows it.

I will show a sketch of proof:

We show that for every $q \in [0,1]$: $|CPL(q n, n,\alpha) - q| \leq \sqrt{\frac{-\ln(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{2n}}$ (notice that the bound does not depend on q). We prove it using Hoeffding inequality.
Using (1) we get that for every sequence of random variables $\{Q_n: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$: $|CPL(Q_n n, n, \alpha) - Q_n| \xrightarrow{n \to\infty} 0$ pointwise.
We use (2) with $Q_n := \frac{Bin(n,p)}{n}$ and use the weak law of large numbers to show that $CPL(Bin(n,p), n, \alpha) \xrightarrow[n \to\infty]{P} p$.


Yes, it is true. From the way Clopper & Pearson define the interval $(p_L, p_U)$, the conservatism when seeing data $X=x$ is bounded above by $P(X=x; p=p_U)+P(X=x; p=p_L)$, and this is $O(n^{-1/2})$ for every $p$ (and in fact uniformly in $p$ away from 0 and 1).

Thanks! Can you define mathematically "conservatism"? Also, it would be helpful if you could elaborate more about how their definition implies the bound.

I mean the difference between the actual and nominal confidence level

I don't see how the bound on the conservatism implies convergence in probability of $p_L$

The one-sided coverage error is strictly smaller than the conservatism, by the argument in that paper. Since the conservatism is $O(n^{-1/2})$, so is the one-sided coverage error

And how does the bound on the one-sided coverage error imply the convergence? I think there is another step to make, using the law of large numbers or the convergence of binomial to normal

No, there's no asymptotic approximation here, just like there isn't in a $t$-interval for Normal means. The confidence interval is exact up to the discreteness of the data.

I didn't mean that there is an approximation. I just don't see how this exactness implies the result I want. I managed to prove my result but I suspect there is a simpler proof that using basic ideas from the theory of confidence intervals that I'm not familiar with (I know probability, but not statistics).
